# ruby gems dependency not being installed in lambda function

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, rubygems

I'm trying to deploy an Ruby app to an AWS Lambda function but some gems are not being bundled correctly.

This is the error message in the log:

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: ruby:3.2.v9 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1::runtime:b96ddb9b1905c3979339d7706a5f7cfda1d851593b1255eb0f15ff573c17fd28
Ignoring bigdecimal-3.1.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.4
Ignoring pg-1.5.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine pg --version 1.5.4
Ignoring psych-5.1.1.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine psych --version 5.1.1.1
Ignoring racc-1.7.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.7.3
Ignoring bigdecimal-3.1.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.4
Ignoring stringio-3.0.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine stringio --version 3.0.9
Ignoring stringio-3.0.9 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine stringio --version 3.0.9
```

I've set `bundle config set --local deployment 'true'` and the vendor folder is there with all the necessary gems.
I've also tried `bundle pristine` but I got the same result.

Any pointers on what am I missing would greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Related note: *Some* gems will work even without native extensions. As a last resort, you might be able to ignore the lack of native extensions (at the cost of performance) if you aren't experiencing actual application failures.

Answer (score 1):

### Platforms, Dynamic Libraries, Dependencies, and ENV Variables

#### TL;DR

You're not actually vendoring your gems, and may not be targeting the right platforms or have the right build dependencies on the Lambda image. Please consider deploying with pre-built vendored gems instead.

#### Anlysis and Recommendations

Take a look at some of Bundler's environment variables, and make sure that any gems are built against the dynamic libraries and platforms you'll be using (e.g. many images use muscl instead of glibc). You may also need to [include explicit platforms in your Gemfile](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-platform.1.html) that target both your development environment and your AWS Lambda images, which may be different.

You may want to start by specifically examining some specific environment variables related to vendored gems (which is *not* the same thing as local gems). [Environment variables used by Bundler v2.4](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-config.1.html) include:

> - `cache_all (BUNDLE_CACHE_ALL)`: Cache all gems, including path and git gems. This needs to be explicitly configured on bundler 1 and bundler 2, but will be the default on bundler 3.
> - `cache_all_platforms (BUNDLE_CACHE_ALL_PLATFORMS)`: Cache gems for all platforms.
> - `cache_path (BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH)`: The directory that bundler will place cached gems in when running bundle package, and that bundler will look in when installing gems. Defaults to `vendor/cache`.

Anything that involves *building* gems at runtime on an AWS Lambda may run into dependency problems, so in my personal experience it's really best to pre-build and vendor the gems directly rather than relying on Bundler at runtime. When possible, it's also a good idea to develop against the same image or runtime environment that you will deploy to, which may mean using a Docker container configured the same way as your Lambda to avoid the whole "it works on *my* machine" issue that is so common in these scenarios.